# list unique notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

I am creating an app that will have permission to read user notifications.
So I have implemented NotificationListenerService as shown below

```
class NotifListener : NotificationListenerService() {
   
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        var context = this
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        
            var packageName = sbn?.packageName ?: ""
            var notifId=sbn?.id?:0; //doesn't seem to be unique

            val notification: Notification = sbn!!.notification
            var extras: Bundle? = null
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                extras = notification.extras
                for (key in extras!!.keySet()) {
                
                    var title: String = extras.get("android.title").toString()
                    var text: String = extras.get("android.text").toString()
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        NotificationDBBuilder.getInstance(context).notificationDao()
                            .insertNotification(
                                NotificationEntity(notifId, title, text,packageName,Date().time)
                            )
                    }
                }
                
            }

            extras?.get("android.title")
            // Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationPosted: " + extras?.get("android.title")+" "+extras?.get("android.text")+" "+extras?.get("android.infoText"))
        }
    }
}
```

and I have added it in manifest

```
 <service android:name=".services.NotifListener"
            android:label="Notif"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Now when I logged the notifications that I received, it seems that the onNotificaitionPosted is being called multiple times for the same notification for some applications or some situations. I want to list only Unique notifications. Which parameter should I Use from the notifications as a Unique Key?
Or is there some way to prevent multiple calls for the same notification?
or is it possible that the listener is getting registered multiple times?

Comment: The reason for multiple calls could be that the particular notification is a service notification  which keeps repeating regularly. So, that could be one reason

Comment: And what do you mean by `unique notification`? I could not get it

Comment: So every time my onNotificationPosted is called I am saving the notification to room
When I get all data from room, some notifications have been added twice. I want to print it only once. @Sambhav.K

Comment: Hmmmm. You can check if the notification already exists or not first. Then if it does not exists, add it.

Comment: That is the problem, how do I check if it already exists

Comment: No idea @dhiraj as I have never got to use ROOM